# How to divide Plumeria?

Tags: cuttings, tropical

I have a Plumeria that went gangbusters this summer.  I want to divide the plant and do it all over again for next year.  I am seeking advice on where to take the cuttings.

For reference here is the plant....

[image]

In the next image, I am showing areas that I am considering for cuttings.  The red outlines show where I am certain I can take a cutting.  There are many more, but I am only showing a few in red.

How about the yellow areas?  Can you divide a Plumeria *stem* into several cuttings and propagate that way?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

University of Florida has [a comprehensive discussion](https://edis.ifas.ufl.edu/ep489) of propagation of Plumeria. Stems without leaves will root; key points are to allow the cuttings to dry out and form callus which will assist in preventing deterioration while roots and new shoots are forming, and to keep the potting soil damp but not wet. Note the general principle that the younger the stem material the more likely root formation will be, and the easier it will be to handle the new plant once it does form roots and become independent. A thick stem fits into a 4 inch pot rather poorly.